# AnalysisException: subqueries are not supported in the select list

Tags: sql, impala

I get this error code shown in title when using this following query. I'm trying query two tables to find total patients with hearing issues and the total of those patients with hearing issues who have undergone some sort of scan (MR,SC,CT).

```
SELECT (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM hearing_evaluation 
        where severity_of_hearing_loss <> 'Normal'
        AND severity_of_hearing_loss <> 'insufficient data'
    ) AS patients_with_hearing_loss
    , AVG(number_of_scans) AS avg_number_of_scans
FROM (
    SELECT patient_id, COUNT(*) AS number_of_scans
    from imaging
    where patient_id IN (
        SELECT patient_id
        from hearing_evaluation
        where severity_of_hearing_loss <> 'Normal'
        and severity_of_hearing_loss <> 'insufficient data'
    )
    AND modality IN ('CT','MR','SC') 
    GROUP BY patient_id
) AS scans
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a code formatting option in the question editor - please use it.

Comment: You have tagged MySQL, SQL Server & Impala as your RDBMS - I assume this was an accident? Please untag those which are not relevant.

Comment: OK I've untagged them all for you. Please add back the relevant tag so that it gets seen by the appropriate members of SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried, pls refer to below SQL - this will work in impala. Only issue i can see is, if hearing_evaluation has multiple patient ids for a given patient id, you need to de-duplicate the data.
There can be case when patient id doesnt exist in image table - in such case you need to apply RIGHT JOIN.

`SELECT 
COUNT(patient_id) AS patients_with_hearing_loss
    , AVG(rs.number_of_scans) AS avg_number_of_scans
FROM (
    SELECT i.patient_id patient_id, COUNT(*) AS number_of_scans 
    from imaging i ,hearing_evaluation h
    where i. patient_id = h.patient_id 
        and h.severity_of_hearing_loss <> 'Normal'
        and h.severity_of_hearing_loss <> 'insufficient data'
    AND modality IN ('CT','MR','SC') 
    GROUP BY i.patient_id ) rs`